# Maximum value in a column

Tags: php, mysql, max

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I want the maximum value of a column (int) in a given MySQL table using PHP.

```
$results = $conn->query("SELECT statement_id FROM statement ORDER BY statement_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$next_statment_id = $results->fetch_assoc();
$next_statment_id = $next_statment_id['statement_id'];
echo $next_statment_id;
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(statement_id) AS max_statement_id FROM statement;`

Comment: Your method seems perfectly efficient to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 10000000 |
+----------+

SELECT i FROM test ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1;
+----------+
| i        |
+----------+
| 18482903 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT MAX(i) FROM test;
+----------+
| MAX(i)   |
+----------+
| 18482903 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See. Not much in it.

Answer (score 2):

[MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) is an OK method too

```
SELECT MAX(statement_id) AS statementIdentity 
  FROM statement;
```

output produce something like this:-

```
+-------------------+
| statementIdentity |
+-------------------+
|       4           |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: @Mark Please try above query and update accordingly! Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not? It Can be done and also working  efficiently fine!